# Select all row except 2 columns

Tags: jquery

This is my snippet that I use to check a checkbox placed in the first column of a row.

```
$('[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:first)').each(function (index) {

    // Selection of entire row
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {

        // Check status of checkbox
        if ($(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('checked')) {
            $(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
        }
        else
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
    });
});
```

But I want to avoid the click action on specific columns of my gridview, for example (last and third columns). I'm not able to apply a selection for "this" element. Could you give me some examples? Please.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the index of the column in the callback this way:

```
$('[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:first)').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
         var index = $(event.target).closest("td").index();
         // you may now test if index is 3 or the last one
```

An alternative would be to bind not to the rows but to the cells

```
$('[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:first) td').each(function (index) {
    var $cell = $(this);
    $cell.on('click', function (e) {
         var $row = $cell.closest("tr");
```

Note that you might prefer to use delegation to reduce the number of bindings if you have big tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:first)').each(function (index) {
    var row = $(this);
    var checkbox = row.find("input:checkbox");

    row.children('td:not(:last-child)').each(function(ndx) { //skip last cell
        if(ndx == 2) return true; //skip third cell

        $(this).on('click', function (e) {

            // Check status of checkbox
            if (checkbox.attr('checked')) {
                checkbox.attr('checked', false);
            }
            else
                checkbox.attr("checked", true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a good solution. Thank you very much.
But If I want to exclude a <select> element by the area of a column? How can I do?

Comment: Such as in this picture https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwERYhF7jyxQWFFPQV9pVjYyQkE
"yes" indicates selectable area
"no" the "select" element is not a selectable area.

Comment: You are welcome. I know only one solution - add another click-handler for the selects inside the cells to stop propogation of click-event: `$('td > select').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: Can you add the entire code, such as my first example? Please

Comment: Perfect I solve with stopPropagation by adding the line inside "row.children each function()". thank you very much Sergey! =)

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution but this doesn't work because I had to apply a further correction inside the if-else, by adding "parent()".
So I solved in this way:

```
        $('[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:first)').each(function (index) {

        // Seleziono gli elementi che non mi interessano
        //var $exclude = $(this).find("select");
        // Seleziono tutta l'area della riga tranne l'ultima colonna
        $(this).find('td:not(:nth-last-child(2))').on('click', function (e) {
            // Controllo lo stato del checkbox
            if ($(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").attr('checked')) {
                $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
            }
            else
                $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
        });
    });
```